# siunitx in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx

I have a tabularx-table with a lot of SI values. For this, I wanted to define a new column type u which places the contents of the column into a \SI{XXX}{cm} expression.

```
\newcolumntype{u}{>{\SI\begingroup}{X}<{\endgroup{cm}}}
```

Using this in a tabularx-table throws me an "Illegal pream token X" and "invalid-token-in-number" exception. Replacing X with c leaves me with only the "invalid-token"-exception.
What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which reproduces your error.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do what you desire is to use the `collcell` package:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand{\MyCommand}[1]{\SI{#1}{cm}}

\newcolumntype{u}{>{\collectcell\MyCommand}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l u}
  \toprule
    1 inch  & 2.54 \\
    1 meter & 100  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```